# django rest framework category parent and child count

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

There is my model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
.....
slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name=_('Slug'))
description = RedactorField(verbose_name=_('Description'))
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
                           default=None, verbose_name=_('Parent'))
```

The thing is I need to make a api resource, using DjangoRestFramework, and serializer should contain count of childs for each category.
Something like this, i made with inbox DRF tools like generics.ListAPIView:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "created": "01-08-2017 10:42 UTC",
    "modified": "01-08-2017 10:55 UTC",
    "name": "Category_1",
    "slug": "",
    "description": "",
    "parent": null,
    "child_count": 12,

},
{
    "id": 2,
    "created": "01-08-2017 10:42 UTC",
    "modified": "01-08-2017 10:55 UTC",
    "name": "SubCategory_1_1",
    "slug": "",
    "description": "",
    "parent": 1,
    "child_count": 0,
},
...
]
```

so the queryset

```
Category.objects.annotate(child_count=models.Count('parent'))
```

gonna show only the count of parents (and its always equals to 1 or 0).

There is MPTTModel lib, that possibly could solve this, but i can't use it, because of some project specific issues exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is should work:

   `Category.objects.annotate(child_count=Count('category_set'))`

`'category_set'` is the name that django auto-generates to use it in reverse relations, you should add `related_name='children'` to the `parent` field and then you can use `Count('children')`.

Comment: Almost, part of solution is  Count('category') ( instead of Count('category_set') ). But thing is I need to know count of all childs, and childs of their childs. For example: Cat_1 is a parent of Cat_1_0 and Cat_1_1, at the same time Cat_1_1 is the parent of Cat_1_1_0 and Cat_1_1_1, so Cat_1 got 2 childs and 2 subchilds ( and total number of childs, that i need to count is 4. And solution Count('category') shows only 2.

Comment: I think one way to do this is to iterate over the `Category` tree and save the count in a dictionary (category_id: count) and then cache it. Then you can get the count from the cached dict. Invalidate the cached value once you add/remove a new `Category`. In this way you don't need to get the count by iterating over the tree each time.